# Why does Javascript engine need to create an Activation Object each time a function is called?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

To sum up the concept of scope chaining:

As soon as a web page is loaded, Javascript locates function definitions and creates a so-called **Variable Object** to each one.
Each VO has to reference each local variables (or global) and so start with the first ancestor's function until the global context. 
Each function's scope chain is stored in the function property called: Scope.

Besides, when a function is called, a new object is created: an **Activation Object**.

What is this? :

It acts like a variable object(actually it is a VO) responsible for referencing all function internal's variable objects including the "arguments" object and formal parameters.

Of course, each of the chain composing of function ancestor's variable objects + function's Activation Object maps **at least** all variables to `undefined` firstly. Then, it evolves by updating its values (corresponding to referenced variables) as long as the execution progresses.

However, I notice Activation Object is different from a Variable Object solely because it contains the **Arguments** object and that this fact would prevent it to be created before function was called.

So, I wonder why people who built the Javascript engine didn't assign **at the function's definition step** each of the Activation Objects. Thus, when a function would be called, no need to create its own specific Activation Object since it already exists. Engine would just clear the corresponding arguments object at the end of the function execution so that the next call to this one could be possible without side effects.

Might it improve performance? Indeed, recreate a whole Activation Object at each call might consume.. Or is there an issue with this proposal?

Comment: I believe that as of ECMAScript 5 there is no "activation object". It's now called the "variable environment". Also, [this excellent article by Angus Croll](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/understanding-javascript-closures/) may help clear things up a bit.

Comment: In older languages like C, the "activation record" was allocated on the stack - it was the "stack frame", in other words. In JavaScript, activation records can "survive" past the end of a function call when the function exposes a closure by instantiating a function and returning it (or binding it to some global object).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activation objects represent the context of a function **invocation**.  Each invocation must have its own object.  They are what allow for closures etc.

Think of it as being analogous to the stack frame allocated for a call to a C or C++ function.

*edit* — here's an example function:

```
function makeCounter( count ) {
  return function() {
    return count++;
  };
}
```

Now, I can make a counter function with that:

```
var counter1 = makeCounter(1);
alert(counter1()); // alerts "1"
alert(counter1()); // alerts "2"
```

What if I make another one?

```
var counter100 = makeCounter(100);
alert(counter100()); // alerts "100"
```

If both calls to `makeCounter()` shared a single `arguments` instance, what would happen when I subsequently called "counter1()"?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't contradict what I wrote. I wonder why each of those activation objects are not created at function definition step solely.

Comment: @Mik378 because the object represents each distinct **invocation** of the function.  Every invocation **must** have its own `arguments` instance etc.

Comment: This is what I said :) " Engine would just clear the corresponding arguments object ". For instance the test(color) function has its own activation object created at call execution. My question was: why not create it at the function definition step and refreshing it (clearing the array-like arguments object) each time this same function would be recalled instead of rebuilding all local variables mapping each time. Because anyway, internal local variables are assigned to undefined until the execution progresses and updates them.

Comment: The arguments object represents the parameters, which are part of the invocation context. What if the function call returned a function, which in turn referenced a parameter from the original one?  If the arguments instance were later cleared out, then the closure would be corrupted.

Comment: @Mik378 see the edit to the answer. Note that due to the weird way that `arguments` works, the elements of the pseudo-array are actually aliases for the parameters.

Comment: Hummmm I get it ;) So assuming test(color) returning test2() function. We would have:  var exampleClosure = test(color);   And nothing prevents to recall just after this line :    test(color) . This would clear the arguments objects (with my solution) and so the future statement:  exampleClosure();  would failed.

Comment: @Mik378 thanks!  The `arguments` object is a really strange thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a single Activation Object per function, reused across invocations, because there may be multiple invocations of a function in progress at any given time. One obvious example of this is recursion.

Perhaps you could have, say, 1 eagerly-allocated AO for each function, so at least the *first* call would be able to use it, but I imagine that kind of mechanism would just complicate the concept for, at best, a nominal performance gain (while also trading off memory).